# Convert query into cakePHP find statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, cakephp, find, cakephp-1.3

Can any one help me to convert this query into CakePHP find statement

```
SELECT
    SUM(ISNULL(tg_prd_value,0)) as total,MAX(tblMarketingArea.mkt_Area_ID) as mkt_Area_ID,MAX(tblMarketingArea.mkt_Area) as mkt_Area
FROM
    tblTarget right outer join
    tblMarketingArea on (tblMarketingArea.mkt_Area_ID = tblTarget.tg_area_id and tblTarget.tg_month = 1 and tblTarget.tg_year = 2011)
where tblMarketingArea.isDeleted!=1
GROUP BY
    tblMarketingArea.mkt_Area_ID order by tblMarketingArea.mkt_Area_ID
```

i have **"Target"** and **"MarketingArea"** model.(I know the tablenames are not according to the cakephp convention but i have to use these names). Since i am using **sql server** i created **Synonyms** for the tables according to the cake convension

model MarketingArea (marketing_area.php)

```
class MarketingArea extends AppModel{
   var $name='MarketingArea';
   var $primaryKey='mkt_Area_ID';
 }
```

i have tried this binding

```
$this->bindModel(array(
        'hasMany' => array(
            'Target' => array(
                'foreignKey' => 'tg_area_id',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'tg_month' => 1,
                    'tg_year' => 2011
                    )
                                 )
                          )
                     )
                );
```

But still i am facing problem with `SUM(tg_prd_value)`

thankz in advace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless there is some special reason for using the `find` method, I would simply create a model method and use `query()` to execute the SQL statement. And if month and year are parameters, make sure they are integers to avoid an SQL injection attack.